# batch file writes operating system to log file

Tags: batch-file

Our organization has roughly 300 hundred computers, the majority of which are running windows 7. I'd like to verify which machines are running an alternate OS, and batch scripting pushed out through a group policy is the only tool I currently have available. To date, I've been writing very simple logs with entries such as

```
If "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
    copy %BatchLocation%%Batch2% "%startup%" /y
    echo %Date%, %Time%, %COMPUTERNAME%, %USERNAME%, Uninstall, Passed, ErrorLevel=%errorlevel% >> %InstallLog%
) else (
    Echo ---------------------------------------------------------
    echo There was a problem uninstalling EPDM; See Log
    echo %Date%, %Time%, %COMPUTERNAME%, %USERNAME%, Uninstall, Failed, ErrorLevel=%errorlevel% >> %InstallLog%
    Pause
    goto :EOF
)
```

I'd like to be able to add the operating system to the log entries as another comma delimited entry at the end of the line, but I'm having a hard time doing it.

Using the command

```
 wmic os get caption
```

gives me

```
 Caption
 Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
```

I'd like to ditch the first line, "caption", and add the second to a variable that I can then write to a log file. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Thanks for your help gentlemen. Here's what I've got so far.

::@echo off
::set variables
set OperatingSystem=NotSpecified

wmic os get caption

for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic os get caption') do set OperatingSystem=%%a

pause 

I'm able to create a variable called OperatingSystem, but as soon as I've used the for statement to write to it, for some reason it gets immediately written to a null value. Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set "version=%%a"
```

Then use `%version%`.

Version would then be (for W7/64/HP

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this command, you could do:

```
for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic os get caption') do (
    echo.%%a
)
```

Your just use the `ver` command as mentioned by @Magoo answer.